# SQL Netezza Column to List

Tags: sql, netezza

Seeking assistance for a way to create the Result set below in a single SQL statement.  Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: `SELECT AC9,GROUP_CONCAT(Value) FROM table GROUP BY AC9`

Comment: Error: ERROR:  Function 'group_concat(varchar)' does not exist
Unable to identify a function that satisfies the given argument types You may need to add explicit typecasts (State:42S02, Native Code: 1D)

Comment: Take a look here https://www-304.ibm.com/connections/forums/html/topic?id=a2402d13-1fdc-4e65-b0ad-adbedbe2c9e1

Comment: Thank you Mihai.  I was able to make that recommendation work based on a known set of 2 possible values.                          SELECT a.AC9,
       MAX(CASE a.RNO WHEN 1 THEN a.value ELSE '' END) ||
       MAX(CASE a.RNO WHEN 2 THEN ', '||a.value ELSE '' END)
FROM
(SELECT AC9,
        value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AC9 ORDER BY value) RNO
FROM table) a
GROUP BY a.AC9

Comment: Post it as an answer an accept it,if only for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.AC9, 
   MAX(CASE a.RNO WHEN 1 THEN a.value ELSE '' END) || 
   MAX(CASE a.RNO WHEN 2 THEN ', '||a.value ELSE '' END) 
FROM (SELECT AC9, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AC9 ORDER BY value) RNO FROM table) a 
GROUP BY a.AC9
```